# Can we obtain Location area code in Window phone 7.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

is there any way or API available to obtain the Location Area code in WP 7.1?

Comment: I assume you mean access the GPS information?  The term "Location Area" code is not clear please define it.

Comment: I mean cell tower ID to which my cell is connected to?

Comment: Cell phones don't stay connected to the same physical  cell tower.  Why do you need this information exactly?

Comment: I was just trying to find the id to show that when phone is switching from one tower to another.

Comment: You won't be able to get that information that is handled down at the firmware level.  What problem are you trying to solve with that information?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone SDK does not currently offer capabilities that would let a developer get cell tower information. You are limited to the standard [Location APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431800%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).